# Open App Launch by using Intent on Huawei P30

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

On Huawei P30 Pro/P30 Lite, there are a feature calls **App Launch** on this 
path below:

> Settings > Battery > App launch

I would like to open this activity by using intent. I tried two component names below but it didn't work.

```
 new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity")),
 new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"))
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm facing the same issue, but for now I just created Help Activity to inform the user what to do in case of app not running properly. I foud this solution to prevent HUAWEI from killing services: https://dontkillmyapp.com/huawei

Comment: @MarkWalczak, not yet, I just ask this question some minutes ago :).

Comment: Ok, take your time :) But be so kind and share  the solution if you find it.

Comment: @MarkWalczak, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (already tested on Huawei P30 Lite).

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.bootstart.BootStartActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity"));
```

Comment: You are asking the system to create two intents. The last line is enough (tested with P40 lite)